# Loop through a few statements only once in a class

Tags: python, class, loops, object

I have a class written which counts the terms in a html source code. This class recieves different objects which are parsed. The output values gets stored in a excel file

The problem: Once i call the class it gets executed perfectly. The second time i call it, it over writes the data. I want r,c to initialise only one time in the class and update values accordingly when ever i call different objects. so that it moves to the next row.

```
class counter_class:
    def count(self, tittle, block_code, sheet1):
        blockcode_passed = block_code.count("Passed")
        #blockcode_blocked = block_code.count("Blocked")
        blockcode_fail = block_code.count("Failed")
        blockcode_retest = block_code.count("Retest")
        blockcode_cannot_test = block_code.count("Cannot Test")
        blockcode_completed = block_code.count("Completed")
        blockcode_passwc = block_code.count("Pass With Concern")
        blockcode_untested = block_code.count("Untested")

        ##writing the count values to excel

        r=3
        c=1
        sheet1.write(r, c, tittle)
        c= c + 2
        sheet1.write(r, c, blockcode_passed)
        c= c + 1
        sheet1.write(r, c, blockcode_fail)
        c= c + 1
        sheet1.write(r, c, blockcode_cannot_test)
        c= c + 1
        sheet1.write(r, c, blockcode_passwc)
        c = c + 1
        sheet1.write(r, c, blockcode_untested)
        r=r+1
        c=c+1

##Apps gateway starts here
apps_gateway = soup.find_all("div", {"id":"group-3191427"})
apps_gateway_str = str(apps_gateway)
apps_gateway_obj=counter_class()
apps_gateway_obj.count("appsgateway",apps_gateway_str, sheet1)
```

Can somebody help me out with a logic to solve this issue ?

Comment: how is your class initialized?

Comment: Note that [by convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) class names are usually written with CamelCase names.